# Charting stock price in highchairs from json

Tags: highcharts

What is the best way to chart stock data from the following source in highcharts? I have been having a play around in fiddle but I have been unable to get the data to map in the correct format.

https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/AAPL?apikey=1920dcbb65f52e51cf4ceb45d64d6bd9

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse your data so that it will be readable by Highcharts.

**Example code:**

```
  var ohlc = [],
    volume = [],
    vwap = [],
    mainData = data.historical.length,
    i = 0;

  for (i; i < mainData; i += 1) {

    let date = data.historical[i].date,
      utcTimestamp = new Date(date).getTime();

    ohlc.push([
      utcTimestamp, // the date
      data.historical[i].open, // open
      data.historical[i].high, // high
      data.historical[i].low, // low
      data.historical[i].close // close
    ]);

    volume.push([
      utcTimestamp, // the date
      data.historical[i].volume // the volume
    ]);

    vwap.push([
      utcTimestamp, // the date
      data.historical[i].vwap // the volume
    ]);
  }
```

**Data**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cjt918Lv/

**Take notice:**

- for indicators is necessary to include the relevant modules
- date has to be provide as timestamp format
- the data in Highcharts should be sorted in ascending order, so you will need to reverse them

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.ohlc
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.volume
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.vwap